# Houghlines no detect all lines opencv+python

Tags: python, opencv, lines, hough-transform

I really need help, I'm trying for many days know, how to use the houghlines function of OpenCV with python .

The function does not detect all lines, even when the result of threshold if it's showing. I have some images and the portion of code that I'm using. thank you very much for any help. i'm sorry for my english.

```
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask,(5,5),0)
    ret,edges = cv2.threshold(mask,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
    image = cv2.erode(edges,kernel,iterations = 1)

    lines = cv2.HoughLines(image,1,np.pi/180,105)
    for rho,theta in lines[0]:
        a = np.cos(theta)
        b = np.sin(theta)
        x0 = a*rho
        y0 = b*rho
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
        cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),1)
```

Resulting imagen [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9qd32mhrfjvplsn/Captura%20de%20pantalla%20de%202015-01-14%2009%3A46%3A46.png?dl=0)

Threshold image [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mww4b1joyl1xdao/Captura%20de%20pantalla%20de%202015-01-14%2009%3A47%3A06.png?dl=0)

Comment: try `HoughLinesP` instead, `std::vector<cv::Vec4i> lines;
cv::HoughLinesP(inThres, lines, 1, CV_PI/720.0, 10, 20, 10);` which gives me most of your lines

Comment: yes! thanks so much for the reply! but,
you could me explain the modification of parameters?, and I have another question, how could avoid drawing lines over lines,  ie on the lined just a line, as houghlines always draws two lines together

Answer (score 3):

Is because the for bucle is around lines[0] -> [0] you must try this:

```
for i in  range(0,lines.shape[0]):
    rho,thetha = lines[i,0]
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho`
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),1)
```